# column selection according to values (top 20 columns for each row) in dataframes which have multiple columns while keeping all rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe made by pandas like the following:

```
id-t    t1  t2  t3  t4  t5  t6  t7  t8  t9  t10 t11 t12
id1      2  4   2   0   5   4   4   4   5    5  5   5
id2      0  5   4   3   5   5   6   7   7    8  9   9
id3      2  0   5   4   4   3   5   5   6    7  7   9
id4      4  2   0   5   3   3   3   4   4    4  4   4
id5      2  0   2   4   2   4   4   5   5    6  6   7
```

I need to make a new dataframe from it in which I want to keep all rows while I need just 5 columns with highest probabilities (values).

```
order (highest to lowest)   id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
1                           t1  t4  t8  t3  t1
2                           t3  t5  t9  t5  t4
3                           t6  t6  t10 t9  t8
4                           t8  t7  t11 t7  t3
5                           t9  t8  t12 t12 t12
```

Which means that i need to know for each row which columns have the for example 5 highest values in comparition with other columns. The order of the column lables (titles) are important for me not the exact values. I hope I could explain properly.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. How would the output look like? @somso

Comment: @somso, can you give your input data and expected output data?

Comment: @ Yolo and @Harv Ipan: Thanks for your attention. I tried to clarify my question. I hope it helps.